# Can't save csv file to folder user the BCP job

Tags: sql-server

I can't get my script to save my file to a specified folder that I have permissions to write to.  Here is the script.

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR (8000)
SET @SQL = 'bcp SELECT * FROM LMP_DAILY.dbo.vw_DirDailyActual ORDER by Date, DirCOde queryout
T:\Shared information\SD3\dirdailyactual.csv -T -c';
PRINT @SQL
exec master.xp_cmdshel @sql;
```

I have sqladmin privileges on the DB and the server.  I also, have read/write permissions on the path where I'm try to send the file.

The job runs and completes but not file is being created on my specified path.

Comment: Is `T:` a mapped drive for your user? If I recall correctly, the file-writing is done server-side running as a service account in a service session. Since mapped drives are per-session, the server process has no access to your mapped drives. You'll have to work around it somehow, such as by mapping the drive in the service session or writing the file to a local drive and then copying/moving it.

Comment: Agree with Andrew Medico, but I'd also add you can use the UNC file path, such as \\servername\folder\shared information\SD3\dirdailyactual.csv.

Comment: I did try to pass it using the full qualified name and several other ways such as: \\MyServerName\folder\shared information\SD3\dirdailyactual.csv and "\\MyServerName\folder\shared information\SD3\dirdailyactual.csv"  to no avail.  Script completes but file will not write to specified drive path.  Call you recommend a alternate way to achieve the desired result, which is a sorted table view saved as a comma delimited file save on a specified drive path.